# I want to change java class at run time which is already loaded. how to do this?

Tags: java, javassist

First time  class is created successfully but next time when there is change in class (like add some variables) It throws an error.
Below is my code.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cc=null;
        final ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if (contextClassLoader != null)
        {
            pool.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(contextClassLoader));
        }
        try{

            cc = pool.makeClass(className); 
            cc.defrost();
            for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
                cc.addField(new CtField(resolveCtClass(entry.getValue()), entry.getKey(), cc));
                // add getter
                cc.addMethod(generateGetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                // add setter
                cc.addMethod(generateSetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

            }
            cc.addConstructor(generateConstructor(cc,properties,className));
            CtConstructor defaultCons=new CtConstructor(NO_ARGS, cc);
            defaultCons.setBody(";");
            cc.addConstructor(defaultCons);
            return cc.toClass();
        }catch(Exception e){
            cc = pool.get(className);   
            cc.detach();
            cc = pool.makeClass(className); 
            cc.defrost();
            for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
                cc.addField(new CtField(resolveCtClass(entry.getValue()), entry.getKey(), cc));
                // add getter
                cc.addMethod(generateGetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                // add setter
                cc.addMethod(generateSetter(cc, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

            }
            cc.addConstructor(generateConstructor(cc,properties,className));
            CtConstructor defaultCons=new CtConstructor(NO_ARGS, cc);
            defaultCons.setBody(";");
            cc.addConstructor(defaultCons);
            return **cc.toClass();** // getting error at this line
        }
```

Comment: *getting error at this line* Can you tell us the message?

Comment: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name

Comment: That message kinda underlined the explanation given in my answer...

Answer (score 3):

You need to write [a Java agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) and attach it dynamically to transform a class after it was already loaded. A Java agent defines a method named `agentmain` which takes an instance of `Instrumentation` as its second argument. With such a Java agent, the changes you are allowed to apply are however limited to changing the body of a method, you cannot add members (fields or methods) or change the signature of existing ones.

You call `Instrumentation::redefineClass` to apply a redefinition.

You can [find articles on how to change loaded code](https://www.sitepoint.com/fixing-bugs-in-running-java-code-with-dynamic-attach/) on several places online.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't (easily).

The point is: when the class is **already loaded** then the JVM has already information about that class. The "default" classloader simply does not allow you to **replace** that definition with a new one.

If you want to dynamically **exchange** class definitions, you have to turn to the advanced topic of writing your **own** classloader that allows for such things. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091075/reload-used-classes-at-runtime-java) as starting point.

Comment: Javaassist generates bytecode. But how does bytecode turn into a class at runtime? By a classloader loading that bytecode ... and turning it into a class. There is no relation between "how bytecode comes into existence" and "how classes are loaded.