# reload a class so its static members are re-initialized

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders

Supposed I have a class like the following

```
public class Foo
{
     public static final String FIELD_1 = Env.getProperties("one");
     public static final String FIELD_2 = Env.getProperties("one");

     //....
     public static final String FIELD_N = Env.getProperties("n");
}
```

Obviously, all the `FIELD_*` get populated when we first reference `Foo`.
Suppose my `Env.getProperties(String)` is not purely functional (ie., it could return different values. How? Not important here)

How do I force the class `Foo` to be "reloaded", so that all the class-init code is re-excecuted (just so I could have different values for the static fields)?

(For various reason, I can't make these fields non-static or non-final. 
So please don't suggest solutions like make Foo an interface, with various getter-methods to be overriden)

Thanks

Comment: My bad, I did not notice the Final keyword. Answer deleted.

Comment: If I get you right, you want a snapshot of some state?

Comment: Hmm, no, sorry. I want to be able to change the values of these fields, so that callers can see new values.

Comment: I think it is easier for us to help you if we get a context. I am sorry to say it, but the suggestions you will get will not use static. ;)

Comment: So maybe there is no solution that you will accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971534/how-to-force-java-to-reload-class-upon-instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it!

You may be able to do it with a custom classloader or JRebel but it will be a mega-bodge. Different classes may have read different values from these fields and be out of sync with each other etc.

Constants are supposed to be constant. Follow the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and refactor to a better design.

---

**Minimal refactoring suggestion**

If the fields are reasonably well-named - `FIELD_1`, `FIELD_2` etc. - you may be able to search and replace references to them in all the Java files with `FIELD_1()`, `FIELD_2()`. Then write some code to to replace the constants with static methods:

```
public static String FIELD_1() { return Env.getProperties("one"); }
public static String FIELD_2() { return Env.getProperties("two"); }
//etc.
```

It's a bit ugly, but it will get you where you want to be without resorting to real hacks.

Comment: It's not a problem of different callers get different values (because that's exactly what I'd want).

Comment: @aetheria OP may just be that next guy or girl since the previous coder decided to do it this way...

Comment: @OneTwoThree to me that sounds like questionable design. I don't know what these "various reasons" are but if you have the option to improve the design without breaking a dozen applications I would consider improving the design. Bad design usually always becomes a problem later on, when it's really hard to change.

Comment: Well, OK I admit  these "various reasons" include "this file is 3,000+ lines in length, with (as many fields). And I am not in the mood of re-writing all these. (And that wasn't counting the callers)"

Comment: I feel for you! Could you write some code that performs a refactoring on the Java files? i.e. reads in Java file, alters the way the fields are accessed and writes out a new version? At least then it's not a manual effort.

Comment: I've added a refactoring suggestion.