# Printing instance variable using javasssist

Tags: java, javassist

I have to modify the following class at runtime to print the value of instance variable 'count' at the end of each method.

```
package test.hib.javaassist;

import java.io.IOException;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class JavaAssistTest {

    int count;


    public void doSomething1(){
        count++;
    }

    public void doSomething2(){
        count++;
    }

    public void doSomething3(){
        count++;
    }

    public void doSomething4(){
        count++;
    }

}
```

Following is the main class, where i am trying to alter the byte code with the help of javaassist.

```
package test.hib.javaassist;

import java.io.IOException;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, IOException {

        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass cc = pool.get("test.hib.javaassist.JavaAssistTest");
        CtMethod[] methods = cc.getDeclaredMethods();

        for(CtMethod method : methods){
            if(! (method.getName().equals("main"))){
                method.insertAfter("{System.out.println(count);}");
                //method.insertAfter("System.out.println($type);");
            }
        }

        cc.writeFile();

        System.out.println("Completed editting");

        JavaAssistTest test = new JavaAssistTest();
        test.doSomething1();
        test.doSomething2();
        test.doSomething3();
        test.doSomething4();

        System.out.println("Finished");

    }

}
```

Currently it is printing

```
Completed editting
Finished
```

i want it to print

```
Completed editting
1
2
3
4
Finished
```

Can you pointout the mistake in my code?

Comment: I'd imagine (just guessing) that the class was already loaded, so changes to the .class file won't be reflected in the runtime of the current JVM. You can try reloading the class as described e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3971771/281108

Comment: hmm.... looks lil complicated. I tried a different way of loading the class.   Class testClass = Loader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("test.hib.javaassist.JavaAssistTest");
  JavaAssistTest test = (JavaAssistTest)testClass.newInstance();   But no change in results !!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will not reload the class if it was already loaded.

Comment: Loader doc says 'Unlike a regular class loader, this class loader obtains bytecode from a ClassPool.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javassist API is a bit confusing here. Have a look at the implementation of `writeFile`. It is a shortcut for `writeFile(".")` which saves the class in your program directory and not on the class path. You expect it to override the original class file what this method does not do. Your system class loader will not be able to locate the updated class file.

You can either manually save the class file at the right location using `writeFile(String)` or force the loading of the modified class by calling `cc.toClass()` which forces the loading of the modified class before your class loader looks it up manually.

Comment: Thank you !! cc.toClass() worked. In the end, i have to use this in an application deployed in Tomcat Server. But it is given in the Java doc that the same cannot be applied for applications running on the application server. I have to try using 'toClass(java.lang.ClassLoader loader)'.